# JavaScriptComponentState in Vaadin 8

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8

I am trying to import com.vaadin.shared.ui.JavaScriptComponentState. I used this import in vaadin 7, but when I update to vaadin 8 I can't do this anymore. 
I am using vaadin bom 8.0.3 in the pom. 
Any hints what I am doing wrong here?

```
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.JavaScriptComponentState;


public class Graph extends JavaScriptComponentState {
    private ArrayList<String> nodes;
    private ArrayList<String> edges;

   public ArrayList<String> getNodes() {
       return nodes;
   }

   public ArrayList<String> getEdges() {
       return edges;
   }
}
```

Error:

```
The import com.vaadin.shared.ui.JavaScriptComponentState cannot be resolved
```

Comment: We need to see some code and an error if there is any...

Comment: It's edited. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Make sure you added the right dependencies in the `dependencies` section of the pom.xml. Adding the bom in the `dependencyManagement` section alone is not enough. You need `<dependency><groupId>com.vaadin</groupId><artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId></dependency>`.

Comment: Please add your dependencies section of your pom.xml file.  Something is off

Comment: hey thanks A. Meier had the right hint. :)

Comment: @A.Meier sounds like you should post a proper response for future references :-)

Comment: @Morfic Thank you. I posted the answer below. :-)

Comment: @hhwwww Would you check off the answer, please? That gives both of us reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pom.xml must have the `vaadin-server` dependency. The `vaadin-bom` is not enough.

This goes in your pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other dependencies ... -->
</dependencies>
```